# How can I put multiple books within one document?

Tags: compiling, books

I need to create a compilation of multiple books in one document for a project. Basically the idea is that several people contribute to the project, each with one book. Then the final version will be a "compilation of books".

The issue is that in Latex, the highest level of hierarchy is a chapter. But I want multiple books, each with their own chapters.

How can I achieve this? Thanks for any input

Comment: The highest level is `\part`. Apart from that, you can define something like `\book`, which takes care of resetting the chapter counter. From your question it is not completely clear what you expect `\book` (or whatever you will use) to accomplish. Best add a small complete example with remarks what you want to have differently, starting e.g. with `\part` as divider.

Comment: You write, "The issue is that in Latex, the highest level of hierarchy is a chapter." That's not quite correct, especially if you treat "Latex" as shorthand for the "LaTeX kernel". For sure, it's not the LaTeX kernel but the document class -- the argument of the `\documentclass` instruction -- that defines the full hierarchy of sectioning commands. The `book` and `scrbook` document class provide  `\part`, one level beyond `\chapter`. The [memoir](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir) document class provides `\book`, one level beyond `\part`.

Comment: Is it enough to e.g. compile the books separately and smash the PDF files together, using something like [pdfjam](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam)?